# $_POST is empty when axios send POST request CORS

Tags: php, reactjs, post, cors, cloudflare

When I send POST request with json data in React app to PHP server, $_POST is empty.
And also php://input doesn't work.

I tried with following code.

PHP server side:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "OPTIONS") {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header("Content-Length: 0");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
} else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    echo "Checking case1:\n";
    echo "<br/>";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    var_dump($data);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Checking case2:\n";
    echo "<br/>";
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

React side code:

```
axios.post(
   'https://xx.xx.com/index2.php',
   {
     member: id
   },
   {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
           },
     withCredentials: true
   }
)
```

PHP server is running on CloudFlare.
I wonder if this is related with Cloudflare's cache process or not.

I hope any helps, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps json_decode is failing. If you try reading `php://input` without decoding the json, do you get any data? Also, if the react side is running in the browser, you can see the request in the developer console in the network tab. There, the request data should also be present

Comment: Is the react application sending the correct data? You can inspect network request in your browser's developer tools. Check the request data and see if anything is actually being posted.

Answer (score 0):

**Use headers as below**

It works for me on PHP

```
headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

while sending from axios you need to change headers

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data,multipart/form-data',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
```