# How to solve this 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control in vueJS?

Tags: php, web-services, vue.js, vuejs2

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/webserivcedemo/state.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header contains multiple values `*, *`,but only one is allowed.

I use $http for call webservice.
This is my request code.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      number: "",
      email: "",
      submitdata: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit: function() {
      var data1 = {
        title: this.name,
        body: this.number + this.email
      };
      this.$http
        .post("http://localhost/webserivcedemo/state.php", {
          data: data1
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          this.submitdata = true;
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This is not a problem with the `$http` call, it's a problem with your server returning the wrong header. It needs to be `*`, not `*, *`.

Comment: I try with axios but not working. and my webservice and my vue project both in my local server. and i use nginx.

Comment: use header with axios or any request, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694209/6309457

Comment: It doesn't matter that they're both on your local server, if they're using different port numbers then CORS applies. For CORS to work you must return a suitable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the server. As the error message says, you are currently returning the value `*, *`, which is not valid. Possibly this is because the header `*` is being added in two different places and something is combining them into `*, *`. A workaround to avoid CORS is to proxy everything through a single server.

Comment: If you don't mind send me any example because i am confuse.

Comment: Add a snippet of php code to your question that is responsible for sending the answer. In particular, we are interested in the fragment setting headers.

Comment: which php code you want

Comment: As what @skirtle has said, try to visit your CORS enabling code and see to it that you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'`.

Comment: @Ashruti The fragment that returns the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Thank you guys but i do all thing but not working

Comment: @Ashruti — You still haven't shown us the server-side code that is setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: i use this code in my webservice file header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");      
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

Answer (score 0):

you need to create new file `vue.config.js` and need to add the urls that are needed to access as below.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
        proxy: 'endpoint',
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**solution 1**: please check 1st same port/server like as `http://127.0.0.1:8080` running twist or not?
If twist then close one. then check.

**solution 2**: sometimes problem for extra `/` API endpoint. remove the extra `/` then check.

thank you